# Using JSON_TABLE to convert List into Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, mysql-json

I have a database column (named "product_parents") formatted as a JSON object that contains the following data:

'["A", "B", "G", "H", "C", "E", "P", "R"]'

I want to use JSON_Table to create separate rows for each item.

Ideally I would get something like:

### |product_parent|

|A|
|B|
|C|
|...|
|P|
|R|

I've tried

```
SELECT *
    FROM pmctb.products AS p,
    JSON_TABLE (p.product_parents, '$[*]'
        COLUMNS (
                pp_id FOR ORDINALITY,
                pp_pn VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.header')
                ) AS pp
    WHERE product_uid = "310-000574"
```

($.header was just an attempt since there is no column header) but that just returns the table and the ordinality and gives me nulls for pp_pn.

Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this does the trick with MySQL 8+:

```
create table products (product_parents json);

insert into products values ('["A", "B", "G", "H", "C", "E", "P", "R"]');

select pp
from products,
JSON_TABLE(
  products.product_parents,
  '$[*]' columns (pp varchar(255) path '$')
) t;
```

and the result is:

| pp |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| G |
| H |
| C |
| E |
| P |
| R |

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks for taking the time to help.  It looks like all I needed to do was change the '$.header' to '$' !  I tired "$." but that didn't work!  Could not have done it without your help!